# how to prevent duplicate data in sql

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have developed an email form that sends the data to a sql database. However, I noticed that there can be duplicate emails. Is there something I can add to my php or sql to prevent duplicate emails?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && strlen($_POST['email'])>0 && strlen($_POST['city'])>0)
{
    $good_input = true;
    $email=$_POST['email']; 
    $city=$_POST['city'];  
    mysql_connect("host", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `launchpage` VALUES ('$email', '$city')"); 

}


?>
```

Comment: Add an `unique index` on `email`.

Comment: You should look into using mysqli or PDO since mysql is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the email the primary key for the table:

```
ALTER TABLE launchpage ADD PRIMARY KEY(email);
```

then use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`:

```
mysql_query("REPLACE INTO `launchpage` VALUES ('$email', '$city')");
```

REPLACE updates an existing record if the key exists, otherwise inserts a new record.  The benefit is that the SQL query will not fail like when you try to insert on a UNIQUE index.

Before making the primary key email you'll need to get rid of the duplicates.  See this post: [Delete Duplicate email addresses from Table in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935797/delete-duplicate-email-addresses-from-table-in-mysql)

Comment: New to making primary keys for tables, but would I add something like this? 
    ALTER TABLE launchpage
    ADD PRIMARY KEY ('$email')

Comment: See my above example. You just add the PK once.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
ALTER TABLE launchpage ADD UNIQUE (email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add a `UNIQUE` constraint onto the email column in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE launchpage
ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE INDEX unique_email (email)
```