# delete duplicate records in table using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has student ID and student email address, and I want to delete duplicate email address, I am using MySQL and wondering any good solutions. For any duplicate email address, keep either one is fine.

Sample input,

```
ID1 s1@example.com
ID2 s2@example.com
ID3 s1@example.com
```

Sample output,

```
ID1 s1@example.com
ID2 s2@example.com
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: you should use validation when inserting email in database... if the email address already exits throw error that email already exists,

Comment: @RahmanQaiser, thanks for the advice, and duplicate already there. Any advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: @LinMa are those ids are integer ?

Comment: try SELECT id, table.email FROM table
INNER JOIN (SELECT email FROM table
GROUP BY email HAVING count(email) > 1) dup ON table.email = dup.email

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, yes, ID is integer. Any advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: @RahmanQaiser, thanks for the solution, and I know how to select unique emails and just not sure how to delete duplicate.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935797/delete-duplicate-email-addresses-from-table-in-mysql](Delete Duplicate email addresses from Table in MYSQL)

Comment: @RahmanQaiser, thanks for the reference, the sample you referred to delete all records which has duplicate email, but I want to keep one. :)

Comment: @JakubKania, your solution works for me and could you write an answer so that I can mark it as answered to benefit future people? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete the data using the join and keep the new or old id as per your wish and here how its done

```
delete t1 from table_name t1
join table_name t2 on t1.email = t2.email and t1.id > t2.id
```

This will keep the older id for the duplicate value
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d2925/1

If you want the new id then change `t1.id > t2.id` to `t1.id < t2.id`

Comment: just wondering how SQL engine executed underlying for the query. Not sure for all join group, inside each group if SQL engine enumerate all pairs and remove smaller id in a pair wise way, if so, the complexity will be large.